# Geometry with Circumcenter and Orthocenter

Tags: geometry, vectors

I am stuck on this problem -

Let $O$ and $H$ be the circumcenter and orthocenter of triangle $ABC$, respectively. Let $a$, $b$, and $c$ denote the side lengths.

Find $AH^2 + BH^2+CH^2$ if the circumradius is equal to $7$ and $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 432$.

So far, I've tried using vectors to tease out the solution, but nothing's working. I have found that $OH$ is $3$ but I'm not sure how that helps.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the triangle obtained by drawing at each vertex of $ABC$ a line parallel to its opposite side. These three new lines form a new triangle $A'B'C'$ that can be seen to be similar to the original triangle, with doubled sides. Also, notice that the circumcenter of $A'B'C'$ is the orthocenter of $ABC$, which we denoted $H$. Thus, by Pythagoras,

\begin{gather*}
(HC')^2 = (AC')^2 + AH^2 = a^2 + AH^2\\
(HA')^2 = (BA')^2 + BH^2 = b^2 + BH^2\\
(HB')^2 = (CB')^2 + CH^2 = c^2 + CH^2.
\end{gather*}
Summing the three expressions above and using $HC' = HB' = HA' = 2 \cdot 7 = 14$ (by the similarity relation), we have
$$
3 \cdot 14^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + (CH^2 + AH^2 + BH^2) = 432 + (CH^2 + AH^2 + BH^2)
$$
implying that
$$
CH^2 + AH^2 + BH^2 = 588 - 432 = 156.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Orthocentre distance to triangle vertices as a function of triangle angles:

$\frac{AH}{|cos(α)|}=\frac{BH}{|cos(β)|}=\frac{CH}{|cos(γ)|}=2·R$

$AH^2+BH^2+CH^2=(2·R)^2·(cos^2(α)+cos^2(β)+cos^2(γ))$

$$
\begin{matrix}
\text{replacing:}&cos(α)=\frac{-a^2+b^2+c^2}{2·b·c}&cos(β)=\frac{a^2-b^2+c^2}{2·a·c}&cos(γ)=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2·a·b}\\
\end{matrix}
$$

$cos^2(α)+cos^2(β)+cos^2(γ)=3-\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{(2·R)^2}=3-\frac{432}{(2·7)^2}=\frac{39}{49}$

$AH^2+BH^2+CH^2=(2·7)^2·\frac{39}{49}=156$